# XPATH to exclude certain urls with wildcard

Tags: xpath, wildcard

I have the following XPATH selection.

//BLOCKQUOTE[@class='postcontent restore ']/A

Now i want to exclude certain links using wildcard.

Where attribute @href!="http://domain.com/download.php *'

How do I this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use**:

```
//BLOCKQUOTE[@class='postcontent restore ']
      /A[@href = 'http://domain.com/download.php']
```

This selects any `A` element in the XML document, whose `href` attribute is `'http://domain.com/download.php'` and that is a child of any `BLOCKQUOTE` element in the XML document, whose `class` attribute has string value `'postcontent restore '`

**If you want the selected links to have *any* URL pointing to that domain, use:**

```
//BLOCKQUOTE[@class='postcontent restore ']
      /A[starts-with(@href, 'http://domain.com/download.php')]
```

**Update**: In a comment the OP clarified:

> I want to exclude... anything starting with that link/url

**Use**:

```
//BLOCKQUOTE[@class='postcontent restore ']
      /A[not(starts-with(@href, 'http://domain.com/download.php'))]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply .... I want to exclude... anything starting with that link/url..... I tried the following operator !=  but it only work for a specific link where i want to use a wild card exclusion for starting with http://domain.com/download.php so urls like http://domain.com/download.php?11 - http://domain.com/download.php?2 5- http://domain.com/download.php?32 get excluded from selection.